# Javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

Here is a code, and  I am unable to find the error, Please help me to fix it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var person={
    first_name:"John",
    last_name:"doe",
    id:5577
    fullName function(){
        return this.first_name+" "+this.last_name;
    }
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=person.fullName();
</script>
```

Google show error in this line

```
fullName function(){
```

Comment: Consider using tools such as [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) or [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to help find common typing errors (as well as optionally checking for your choice of stylistic rules). Many editors have plugins for at least one of them to give you feedback while you type.

Comment: Have a look at a JavaScript tutorial: http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

old school (internet explorer), you need to change as the previous answers stated

```
var person={
    first_name:"John",
    last_name:"doe",
    id:5577,
    //     ^ missing comma
    fullName: function(){
    //      ^ missing colon
        return this.first_name+" "+this.last_name;
    }
}
```

ES2015 (ES6) has a shorthand

```
var person={
    first_name:"John",
    last_name:"doe",
    id:5577,
    //     ^ missing comma
    fullName(){
    //      ^ no need for "function" keyword
        return this.first_name+" "+this.last_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the comma here:

```
id:5577,
```

and the colon here:

```
fullName:function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is what your code should look like (with your errors in comments):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var person={
    first_name:"John",
    last_name:"doe",
    id:5577,                                           //missing coma
    fullName:function(){                               //missing colon
        return this.first_name+" "+this.last_name;
    }
}

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=person.fullName();
</script>
```